# Do crawlers skip content enclosed in the html small tag?

Tags: indexing, web-crawler

I was wondering whether the `small` tag indicates to crawlers that its content isn't relevant and so it will be skipped and not indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dependent on the crawler implementation.

I'm not aware of any formal or informal standard that `small` tags prevent content from being indexed, and it [doesn't appear](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/01/controlling-how-search-engines-access.html) to be [mentioned by major search engines](http://www.ysearchblog.com/2008/06/03/one-standard-fits-all-robots-exclusion-protocol-for-yahoo-google-and-microsoft/) when [discussing control over what's indexed](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/06/improving-on-robots-exclusion-protocol.html).

[The original Google search engine](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~backrub/google.html) gave extra weight to larger fonts - so you might expect a large font to be considered *more* relevant, but this doesn't mean that smaller fonts don't get indexed.

There is no standard for preventing parts of a page from being indexed. For an approach that might work on some engines, there is the [`class="robots-nocontent"`](http://www.ysearchblog.com/2007/05/02/introducing-robots-nocontent-for-page-sections/) which was introduced by (and I think only supported by) Yahoo - so unfortunately I wouldn't expect it to work across other engines.